# Error Firebase: db is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, web, google-cloud-firestore

A la hora de correr la página la consola me arroja "Uncaught ReferenceError: db is not defined". mi código es este:

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.10.1/firebase.js"></script>

    <script>
        // Your web app's Firebase configuration
        var firebaseConfig = {
            apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            authDomain: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            databaseURL: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            projectId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            storageBucket: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            messagingSenderId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            appId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        };
        // Initialize Firebase
        firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    </script>
    <script>
        var citiesRef = db.collection("cities");

citiesRef.doc("SF").set({
    name: "San Francisco", state: "CA", country: "USA",
    capital: false, population: 860000 });
    </script>
    <script src="../bootstrap/jquery.slim.js"></script>
    <script src="../bootstrap/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Espero puedan ayudarme, nunca había tenido este problema. Incluso intenté ver si se resolvía ejecutando Xampp y no fue así.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hace falta que insertes los scripts de Javascript respectivos de firebase y firestore, intenta hacerlo de esta manera:

```
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.10.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.10.1/firebase-firestore.js">/script>

    <script>
        // Your web app's Firebase configuration
        var firebaseConfig = {
            apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            authDomain: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            databaseURL: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            projectId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            storageBucket: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            messagingSenderId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            appId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        };
        // Initialize Firebase
        firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

        const db = firebase.firestore();
    </script>
    <script>
        var citiesRef = db.collection("cities");

        citiesRef.doc("SF").set({
            name: "San Francisco", state: "CA", country: "USA",
            capital: false, population: 860000 });
    </script>
    <script src="../bootstrap/jquery.slim.js"></script>
    <script src="../bootstrap/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Te lo agradezco.

Comment: Que bien que haya funcionado. Es un gusto ser de ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Utilizas db pero en ningún momento lo declaras y como el sdk de firebase no tiene incluido ese objeto te da error, en tu caso quieres acceder al objeto que maneja las base de datos de firebase que es:

```
 firebase.database()
```

Esto es así porque el objeto principal del sdk es "firebase".

Ahora y me imagino que lo viste en algún ejemplo tienes la variable db pero eso se hace para almacenar el objeto database de manera que no tengamos que escribir constantemente la instrucción mencionada con anterioridad:

```
  var db = firebase.database()
```

Para luego poder usarlo como lo tienes

```
  db.[función()]
```

Por otra parte, te recomiendo leer completo esto: https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup/ además de mencionar lo que acabo de explicar te muestran que es una buena práctica no cargar todo el sdk como lo estás haciendo sino indicar qué componentes necesitas por separado, en tu caso es el core y database.

```
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.10.1/firebase-app.js"></script>

  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.10.1/firebase-database.js"></script>
```

Me parece que esa función collection no existe, la documentación indica que para acceder a la base de datos tienes que usar la función .ref():

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Database

Además te dejo el link del proyecto de muestra en el que indican como acceder a la base de datos para guardar y leer datos:

https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/blob/master/database/README.md

Comment: Ya intenté declararla de esa manera y ahora me marca que "db.collection" no es una función. Según yo, agregué todo lo necesario para las pruebas, para que cuando funcione seleccione sólo lo que necesito. Voy a seguir tu consejo, gracias.

Comment: Edite la respuesta.

Comment: Al declararla con "var db = firebase.database()" el error ahora arrojado es "db.collection is not a function"

Comment: Si por eso, no existe. Debes usar la función ref() al menos es lo que dice la documentación y como está en los ejemplos

Comment: Creo que el usuario lo que intenta hacer es conectarse a Cloud Firestore, no a Realtime Database, entonces  debe añadir:   <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.10.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>

Comment: Entiendo eso, pero esa solución es para Real Time Database y yo estoy usando Cloud Firestore

Comment: Mi error es con Firestore

Comment: Ah vale como decía db jure que era database. Reviso a ver si veo algo pero igual debes ir a la documentación ya que es lo mismo que estaría haciendo yo ahora, busca en el mismo link de los ejemplos uno que sea sobre firestore la documentación te dice todo.

Comment: Te lo agradezco, ya quedó.